# Having trouble converting textfield to integer and more

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton

a little information on my assignment:

**Based on the Person class previously defined, design your own Java application that displays a form for a user to enter their name, year_of_birth and employment status. The provided data will be used to instantiate a Person object. The form should also include a JButton and a JTextField. When the user clicks on the JButton the application should display “Welcome [name]! You are [age] old. Time has been kind to you.”, where [name] and [age] are the current values of the name and age attributes of the Person object.**

I am a little new to creating GUI's. I have used the jFrame design that allows me to create the design of the GUI. I am having trouble using that form to display the results. Specifically, having the button display the results, having there name stored in a variable once they type it in, and brining up a dialog box once the button is clicked with the message.

```
package my.userFormUI;

/**
 *
 * @author Randy
 */
public class userFormUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form userFormUI
     */
    public userFormUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    int age;
    int year;

    public int getAge(int year_of_birth){//get year method
        age = 2014 - year_of_birth;
    return age;
}//end method

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jDialog1 = new javax.swing.JDialog();
        jDialog2 = new javax.swing.JDialog();
        jDialog3 = new javax.swing.JDialog();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        name = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        year_of_birth = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jRadioButton1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        jRadioButton2 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jDialog1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jDialog1.getContentPane());
        jDialog1.getContentPane().setLayout(jDialog1Layout);
        jDialog1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jDialog1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jDialog1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jDialog1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jDialog2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jDialog2.getContentPane());
        jDialog2.getContentPane().setLayout(jDialog2Layout);
        jDialog2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jDialog2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jDialog2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jDialog2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jDialog3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jDialog3.getContentPane());
        jDialog3.getContentPane().setLayout(jDialog3Layout);
        jDialog3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jDialog3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jDialog3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jDialog3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "User Information", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 12), new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0))); // NOI18N

        jLabel1.setText("NAME:");

        jLabel2.setText("YEAR BORN:");

        jLabel3.setText("EMPLOYMENT STATUS:");

        name.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                nameActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        year_of_birth.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                year_of_birthActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jRadioButton1.setText("Employed");

        jRadioButton2.setText("Unemployed");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jRadioButton2)
                            .addComponent(jRadioButton1))
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(name, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 196, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(year_of_birth, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 41, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(name, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(year_of_birth, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jRadioButton1))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jRadioButton2)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jButton1.setText("SUBMIT");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(39, 39, 39)
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 84, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(14, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(104, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>
```

This is where my coding needs to begin.

```
    private void year_of_birthActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    int year = Integer.parseInt(year_of_birth.getText());
    getAge(year);




    }//attempted to convert a string to an integer here                                             


    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here        
        System.out.println("Welcome" + name + " ! You are " + getAge(year) + " old. Time has been kind to you.");
    }//Code for button here                                      



    private void nameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }//name text field                                    

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(userFormUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(userFormUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(userFormUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(userFormUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new userFormUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JDialog jDialog1;
    private javax.swing.JDialog jDialog2;
    private javax.swing.JDialog jDialog3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton1;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField name;
    private javax.swing.JTextField year_of_birth;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am already past the due date and very confused on how coding for GUI's go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a event for every textField. This:

```
    name.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            nameActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    year_of_birth.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            year_of_birthActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
```

I wipe this fragment of code.

You only need an event when the user click the button, therefore this event what you'll need.
Instead of the methods `nameActionPerformed()` and `year_of_birthActionPerformed()`, I would create a `getName()` and `getYearOfBirth()` methods.

```
private String getName(){
     return name.getText();
}

private int getYearOfBirth(){
     return Integer.parseInt(year_of_birth.getText());
}
```

Then, in the method of button event:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {   
    String name = getName();
    int year = getYearOfBirth();
    System.out.println("Welcome" + name + " ! You are " + getAge(year) + " old. Time has been kind to you.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is whole lot of unnecessary code you have. you need to clean it up for example you have 3 dialog instances. you do not need them. coming to your question you need to write implementation like:

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            // This will display message
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Welcome" + name.getText() + " ! You are " + getAge(Integer.parseInt(year_of_berth.getText())) + " old. Time has been kind to you.");

// here you need to write code to populate your Person Object.
        }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Really I cannot believe it was that simple. It works great thank you.

Comment: @RandyGilman Glad that helped you .. have fun coding :) and please do not forget to up vote/accept answer :)